# Какая строка кода приводит к ошибке компиляции или времени исполнения?

Tags: c++

Класс ExtendedMuxer содержит буфер (член m_buffer) нужный для работы с аудиоданными. Размер буфера устанавливается один раз в конструкторе класса и там же под буфер выделяется память. В каждом методе класса в самом начале стоит проверка и если под буфер не выделена память, то сразу происходит возврат из метода. В методе Finalize, делающем некую очистку, подобная проверка заканчивается не возвратом из метода, а генерацией исключения. Какая строка кода приводит к ошибке компиляции или времени исполнения? 
Исходник:

```
        class BasicMuxer {  /*skipped */ };

    class ExtendedMuxer : public BasicMuxer
    {
        char* m_buffer;
        /* code skipped */
    public: 
        ExtendedMuxer(int size);
        /* code skipped */
        void Finalize() throw(std::exception);
        virtual ~ExtendedMuxer();
    };

    ExtendedMuxer::ExtendedMuxer(int size)
    {
        if (size < 1024)
            m_buffer = new char[size];
        else
            m_buffer = 0;
        /* code skipped */
    }
    /* code skipped */

    void ExtendedMuxer::Finalize() throw(std::exception)
    {
        if (!m_buffer) throw(new std::exception);
        /* code skipped */
    }

    ExtendedMuxer::~ExtendedMuxer() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Finalize();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            delete[] m_buffer;
            throw;
        }
        delete[] m_buffer;
    }
```

Варианты строк где это может происходить:
throw;
или в:
delete[] m_buffer;
или в:
catch(...) {
или в:
if (!m_buffer) throw(new std::exception);
или в:
void Finalize() throw(std::exception);

Comment: А зачем гадать? Компилятор всегда показывает ошибку компиляции если такая присутствует.

Comment: У меня VisualStudio 15 и Haker Rank Code без ошибок прогоняют этот код, я не знаю, почему ни один из компилеров не показывает ошибку...

Comment: Может быть проблема во времени исполнения. Полагаю в строке:

Comment: if (!m_buffer) throw(new std::exception);

Comment: Может ли строка:         throw;       во фрагменте кода: catch (...)
 {
  delete[] m_buffer;
  throw;
 }
делать проблему во времени исполнения, или ошибку. Среды разработки (мои) компилируют без ошибок и без этой проблемы. Помогите, плиз!!!

Comment: Запустите под отладчиком, он остановится на проблемной строке.

Comment: @Игорь: Зачем вы придумываете какие-то странные сказки про "ошибка компиляции или выполнения"? У вас есть ошибки компиляции или нет? Если нет, то к чему это тут? А будут ли тут ошибки выполнения - откуда ж нам знать? Выполняйте код: если будут, то будут, если не будут - то не будут. О чем вопрос вообще? О каких "ошибках выполнения" вообще может идти речь, если кода программы даже отдаленно не приведено.

Comment: Владимир, я привел исходник программы, выше на странице. Вопрос: Какая строка кода приводит к ошибке компиляции или времени исполнения? Я не придумываю сам, мне поручено найти ошибку. Код выполняется, в этом и неясность...Попробую с запуском отладчика. Спасибо!

Comment: код страшный, как не знаю что.  Первое, что бросается в глаза - ручные манипуляции с буфером. Проще и дешевле выделить все в `std::vector<char>` и половина кода просто уйдет. Второе - это бросание исключения в деструкторе.  Так лучше не делать, если не понимаете, что это такое.

Comment: Спасибо! Код не мой, мне поручено исправить. Я отладчиком нашел замечание в строке:    trow;      - "function assumed not to throw an exception but does.   - Предполагается, что функция не генерирует исключение, но делает это". Вот это и есть проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Из того, что приведено, ошибка может быть только если в рантайме создавался объект ExtendedMuxer с `size`ом больше 1024 (вот тут-то и бросить бы исключение, нет?). Соответственно, при уничтожении объекта, деструктор вызовет `Finalize()`, `Finalize` бросит исключение (так как `m_buffer` равен нулю), деструктор его отловит, и бросит новое. Кем последнее ловится из этого кода не понятно. А вообще, для таких случаев, используйте `TRACE`ы или логи, например.